# Android Firebase notification when application starts

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I’m new to android.I programmed an app that uses Firebase to get push notifications. If I send a notification from the Firebase interface, the device receives the notification only when the app is running. Is there a way to get the notifications when the app is not running or at least to get all the unseen notifications when the app starts up?

Thank you in advance!

---

I add my code...

This is the class extending the FirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody)
    {
        //Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("My app");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        //notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

and this is the class extending the FirebaseInstanceIdService:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token)
    {

    }

}
```

Finally, this is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="user.pushnotificationexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There is a different problem may be in your code! Put your priority `high`! And also use data messages and not Firebase Console

Comment: Thank you @Xenolion for your comment! I put my priority "high" but It is the same! What about the code?

Comment: What I am suprised is that your question is vice versa! A lot of people always complain they lack notifications when app is running! But a point to note is that! Your `onMessageReceived` method will not be called if your app is not running and the Firebase SDK will show notifications itself. Solve it using Data Messages! They always work! Do not use the Firebase Console (Interface).

Comment: Just set your own server easily and send your notifications from there!. It is easier and free to transfer data than struggling with Firebase own default implementations!

Comment: As  Xenolion  indicated, FCM handles messages differently depending on whether you are sending a `Notification` ,  `Data` or hybrid message! Please read the FCM documentation carefully and be aware that Android and iOS handle FCM Messages differently as well. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 0):

This is Xamarin Android solution, but it should get you close to native.

Try test sending a "data" push notification from an online tester like "pushwatch". Make sure to click the json checkbox and add a json payload that includes the key, "data":

{"data": {"title":"This is a title!","body":"This is the body text!"}}

The OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) method, message parameter, has a dictionary property "Data": i.e. message.Data. You'll find the json payload key value pairs (title & body) in that dictionary.

Note, if the app is STOPPED, the user will OPEN the notification and Android will open the app, targeting the Activity used in the pending intent created and used to build the local notification (see below). You will need to handle the notification intent from the OnCreate method of your target Activity ( otherwise if the app is running,  you'll handle the intent from an override of OnNewIntent).

```
public class MainActivity....
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ...
        var pushExtra = Intent.GetStringExtra("your.pushextra.key");

        if(pushExtra != null)
        {
          MyType myType = JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyType>(pushExtra);
          //if you have a framework like MVVM or startup process 
          //and your type
          //is used for app navigation, you may need to store
          //the string value in shared preferences and deserialize
          //and use it later
          //after the app has completely finished starting
        }
    }
}
```

Save yourself some effort, if you need a type or dictionary here, make sure to serialize the object when putting the extra (when you create the local notification) and then deserialize the pushExtra to your concrete type to use an instance of it above. You may find most examples put a string, or int or dictionary of key value pairs.

```
void ConfigureLocalNotification(MyType typeInstance)
{
     ...
     var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
     var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(typeInstance);
     Log.Info(TAG, $"Adding IntentExtra: {jsonData}");
     intent.PutExtra("your.pushextra.key", jsonData);

     intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop |
     ActivityFlags.IncludeStoppedPackages); //| ActivityFlags.NewTask);

     var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent,
     PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

     ....
     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = null;
     builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context ...); 
     builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent) ....
}
```

Hope this helps